# Distributing tasks to players hangs program

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

We were given two structs, one representing a Player and another one representing a Task that the player can later implement after it has been assigned to him. Each player has a list of tasks sorted in ascending order. Initially we had to implement a circular doubly linked list with sentinel for the Players list and a singly sorted linked list with sentinel for the tasks (using the tasks_head & tasks_sentinel fields of the Players struct).

Once the data structures are set, we need to distribute the tasks from a given General tasks list (pointed to by Head_GL) to the players using a round robin algo (don't know if my solution is correct, haven't researched the algorithm so that i can try solving the problem on my own first).
The issue is that for some unknown to me reason, the program seems to hang when the `isTaskListEmpty(..)` is called and then the program stops just like that, without printing anything after `cout<<"istasklist empty called";`.

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

P.S. I've never worked with c++ on anything other than simple hello world programs so my experience with pointers is beyond limited.

Header file declarations for the structs and some global variables:

```
/**
 * Structure defining a node of the players double linked list
 * tree
 */
struct Players
{
    int pid;                      /*Player's identifier*/
    int is_alien;                 /*Alien flag*/
    int evidence;                 /*Amount of evidence*/
    struct Players *prev;         /*Pointer to the previous node*/
    struct Players *next;         /*Pointer to the next node*/
    struct Tasks *tasks_head;     /*Pointer to the head of player's task list*/
    struct Tasks *tasks_sentinel; /*Pointer to the sentinel of player's task list*/
};

/**
 * Structure defining a node of the tasks sorted linked list
 */
struct Tasks
{
    int tid;                      /*Task's identifier*/
    int difficulty;               /*Task's difficulty*/
    struct Tasks *next;           /*Pointer to the next node*/  
};

struct Head_GL
{
    int tasks_count[3];           /*Count of tasks*/
    struct Tasks *head;           /*Pointer to the head of general list*/
};

/* Global variable, pointer to the head of the players list */
struct Players *players_head;

/* Global variable, pointer to the head of the tasks list */
struct Head_GL *tasks_head;

/* Global variable, pointer to the top of the completed task's stack */
struct Head_Completed_Task_Stack *tasks_stack;

/* Global variable, counter of the total num of tasks in the general tasks list */
int Total_Tasks;
```

Main.cpp:

```
/**
 * @brief Optional function to initialize data structures that 
 *        need initialization
 *
 * @return 1 on success
 *         0 on failure
 */
int initialize() {
    // players list init
    players_head = (struct Players*) malloc(sizeof(struct Players));
    players_head->evidence = -1;
    players_head->is_alien = -1;
    players_head->pid = -1;
    players_head->next = NULL;
    players_head->prev = NULL;
    players_head->tasks_head = NULL;
    players_head->tasks_sentinel = NULL;

    // General Tasks List init
    tasks_head = (struct Head_GL*) malloc(sizeof(struct Head_GL));
    tasks_head->tasks_count[0] = 0;
    tasks_head->tasks_count[1] = 0;
    tasks_head->tasks_count[2] = 0;
    tasks_head->head = NULL;

    // Completed Tasks stack init
    tasks_stack = (struct Head_Completed_Task_Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Head_Completed_Task_Stack));
    tasks_stack->count = 0;
    tasks_stack->head = NULL;

    Total_Tasks = 0;
    return 1;
}

/**
 * @brief Distribute tasks to the players
 * @return 1 on success
 *         0 on failure
 */
int distribute_tasks() {
    if(isDLLEmpty() || isGenTaskListEmpty()) return 0;

    // round robin algo
    int tasksToAssign;
    struct Players* player = players_head->next; // start with the 1st player
    struct Tasks* task = tasks_head->head; // start with the 1st task

    // There's only one player and he's an impostor so exit
    if(player->is_alien == 1 && player->next == NULL) return 0;

    for(tasksToAssign = Total_Tasks; tasksToAssign > 0; tasksToAssign--) {
        if(player->is_alien == 1 || player == players_head) {
            tasksToAssign++;
            player = player->next; // go to the next player
            continue; // skip impostors
        }

        sortedInsertTaskList(&player,task->tid,task->difficulty);
        player = player->next; // go to the next player
        task = task->next; // go to the next task to assign
    }
    return 1;
}

// Beginning of General Tasks list implementation (Sorted singly linked list)

bool isGenTaskListEmpty() {
    return (tasks_head->head == NULL);
}

int sortedInsertGenTaskList(int tid, int difficulty) {
    // increment the list's difficulty counter
    if (difficulty == 1) tasks_head->tasks_count[0]++;
    else if (difficulty == 2) tasks_head->tasks_count[1]++;
    else tasks_head->tasks_count[2]++;

    Total_Tasks++; // increment the num of total tasks

    struct Tasks *node = (struct Tasks*) malloc(sizeof(struct Tasks)); // could return null if not enough mem
    if(node == NULL) return 0; // not enough memory exit
    // add data to the new node
    node->tid = tid;
    node->difficulty = difficulty;
    node->next = NULL;

    if(isGenTaskListEmpty()) {
        tasks_head->head = node;
        return 1;
    }

    // insert the new node without breaking the sorting of the list
    Tasks *curr = tasks_head->head;

    while(curr->next != NULL && curr->next->difficulty < difficulty) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    node->next = curr->next;
    curr->next = node;
    return 1;
}

void printGenTasksList() {
    cout << "{" << tasks_head->tasks_count[0] << "," << tasks_head->tasks_count[1] << "," << tasks_head->tasks_count[2] << "}" << endl;
    Tasks* curr = tasks_head->head;
    do {
        cout << "Task#" << curr->tid << ":" << curr->difficulty << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    } while (curr != NULL);
}

// End of General Tasks list implementation (Sorted singly linked list)

// Beginning of Tasks List implementation (Sorted Singly Linked List w/sentinel)

bool isTaskListEmpty(struct Tasks* head) {
    cout<<"istasklist empty called";
    return (head->next == NULL);
}

int sortedInsertTaskList(struct Players** player, int tid, int difficulty) {
    struct Tasks* node = (struct Tasks*) malloc(sizeof(struct Tasks)); // could return null if not enough mem
    
    if(node == NULL) return 0;
    // add data to the new node
    node->tid = tid;
    node->difficulty = difficulty;
    node->next = NULL;

    cout << "sortedInsert before is empty";
    if (isTaskListEmpty((*player)->tasks_head)) { // if the list is empty, make the head and sentinel point to the new node
        cout << "list was empty";
        (*player)->tasks_head->next = node;
        (*player)->tasks_sentinel->next = node;
        return 1;
    }

    // check if the new node can be added to the end of the list
    if ((*player)->tasks_sentinel->next->difficulty <= difficulty) {
        (*player)->tasks_sentinel->next->next = node; // place new node at the end of the list
        (*player)->tasks_sentinel->next = node; // update sentinel
        return 1;
    }

    // insert the new node without breaking the sorting of the list
    struct Tasks* curr = (*player)->tasks_head->next;

    while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->difficulty < difficulty) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    node->next = curr->next;
    curr->next = node;
    return 1;
}



// End of Tasks List implementation (Sorted Singly Linked List w/sentinel)

// Beginning of players list implementation (circular doubly linked list w/ Sentinel)

bool isDLLEmpty() {
    return (players_head->next == NULL);
}

int dllInsert(int pid, int isAlien) {
    // allocate memory and initialize fields
    struct Players* player = (struct Players*) malloc(sizeof(struct Players)); // could return null if not enough mem
    if(player == NULL) return 0; // not enough memory, exit
    player->pid = pid;
    player->is_alien = isAlien;
    player->evidence = 0;
    player->prev = players_head;
    player->tasks_head = NULL;
    player->tasks_sentinel = NULL;

    // check if the list is empty
    if (isDLLEmpty()) {
        player->next = players_head;
        players_head->next = player;
        players_head->prev = player;
        return 1;
    }

    // insert the new player at the beginning of the list
    players_head->next->prev = player;
    player->next = players_head->next;
    players_head->next = player;
    return 1;
}



// End of players list implementation (circular doubly linked list w/ Sentinel)
```

Comment: Perhaps that's because the shown code isn't really C++, but old C code? C++ code never uses `malloc`. In any case, what did you see when you ran this program in your debugger?

Comment: our professor was using pseudocode so that's on me probably for not realizing. Haven't used a debugger, i'm working with vs code and cmd, i used the cout statements to "debug"

Comment: Are you able to minimize the code here into a smaller program that still has your concern? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @BillLynch, depends on whether or not people need to see my implementation of the data structures. Maybe the issue lies in there somewhere. Do you reckon i should remove it and only leave in the necessary bits?

Comment: You should remove  everything that's not required by a [mre]. What you basically need to shown is the absolute minimum of code that everyone else can cut/paste, ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce your problem. This is explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Comment: You really need to use a debugger, but you should use "cout << text << endl;" to flush cout, otherwise you may not see the debug messages appear! My guess is that it hangs in the while() loop after isTaskListEmpty()

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail: For example, `dllLookUp`, `printDLL` and `printDLLReverse` are never used. But yes, you should remove unnecessary code that is not required to reproduce the issue. That doesn't mean you should remove data structures, but you should remove fields in those data structures that aren't necessary.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see, however our program reads data from a text file and depending on the data, it adds tasks, implements them, distributes them , adds players etc. In order to be able to copy/paste, compile and run the program i'd need to include everything right? Since this program needs tasks to be added to the general list first, adding players and then distributing the tasks.

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail: Ah! But to reproduce your error do you need to read from a file? Perhaps we could just hardcode a list of 2 elements and it would still fail?

Comment: @BillLynch , correct, we could just hardcode the data needed. I.e. add a player, add some tasks to the general list and then try and distribute them. The error persists. Should i assume that my implementation of the data structures is correct and omit them from the post? If nothing seems wrong, then the problem would probably be with them, right?